# How to ignore case when using str_detect?

Tags: r, stringr

stringr package provides good string functions.

To search for a string (ignoring case)

one could use

```
stringr::str_detect('TOYOTA subaru',ignore.case('toyota'))
```

This works but gives warning

> Please use (fixed|coll|regex)(x, ignore_case = TRUE) instead of ignore.case(x)

What is the right way of rewriting it?

Comment: consider a user that prefers to avoid regex magic

Answer (score 31, accepted):

the search string must be inside function `fixed` and that function has valid parameter ignore_case

```
str_detect('TOYOTA subaru', fixed('toyota', ignore_case=TRUE))
```

Comment: Curiously, why I get the FALSE output from 'regex', what is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 66):

You can use `regex` (or `fixed` as suggested in @lmo's comment depending on what you need) function to make the pattern as detailed in *?modifiers or ?str_detect (see the instruction for pattern parameter)*:

```
library(stringr)
str_detect('TOYOTA subaru', regex('toyota', ignore_case = T))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: or using `fixed`: `str_detect('TOYOTA subaru', fixed('toyota', ignore_case=TRUE))`.

Comment: I love that the question is simple and clear and the answer is simple and clear. A rare treat!

Comment: Currently, I get the FALSE output with stringr at ‘1.4.0’.

Answer (score 43):

You can save a little typing with `(?i)`:

```
c("Toyota", "my TOYOTA", "your Subaru") %>% 
  str_detect( "(?i)toyota" )
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Comment: This is the best answer in for both single and multiple search terms. For example, ```str_detect(X, (?i)cws|usgs|fws)```

Comment: I frequently use this with `str_subset()`. It has saved me a lot of typing.

Comment: (?i) may also be used with `data.table` `%like%` operator for case-insensitive search. Or you may just use `%ilike%` operator which has been made specifically for case-insensitive search.

Comment: Is '(?i)' a way in the original regular expressions?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the base R function `grepl()` to accomplish the same thing without a nested function. It simply accepts `ignore.case` as an argument.

```
grepl("toyota", 'TOYOTA subaru', ignore.case = TRUE)
```

(Note that the order of the first two arguments (pattern and string) are switched between `grepl` and `str_detect`).

Answer (score 2):

Or you can erase all capitalization while you search:

```
str_detect(tolower('TOYOTA subaru'), 'toyota')
```