# Filtering dataframe on regex string across all rows?

Tags: r, dplyr

I've read in a table `df` which has numbers and strings.

I have a keywords stored in a vector `arr_words`. For every row in the table; if row contains any word from the vector ignoring case, I want to keep that row.

For instance, if one of the cells has "i like magIcalot", and one of my keywords is "magic", I want to keep all the attributes from that row.

I've been trying this, but I'm pretty sure it's wrong since it's getting me back zero rows-

```
df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  filter(any(names(df) %in% arr_words))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to search in any specific field say `field1`, you can use as below:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   filter(grepl(arr_words,field1))
```

If you want to search across all fields, then:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(., arr_words)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the really quick reply! It works pretty well, but is not ignoring case when searching; is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Try the comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44530029/r-how-to-ignore-case-when-using-str-detect)

Comment: It worked; thanks a lot! To anyone wondering, it's-

```df %>%
  filter_all(any_vars(str_detect(., regex(arr_words, ignore_case = T))))
```